# Наследование шаблонов

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++

Почему не работает следующий код?

```
template<typename T> class A
{
    public :
        T t;
};

template<typename T> class B : public A<T>
{
    public :
        T f() { return t; }
};
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
In member function 'T B<T>::f()':
error: 't' was not declared in this scope
         T f() { return t; }
                        ^
```

P.S. Компилятор GCC 6.3.0.

Comment: Гм. Спасти положение можно, указав `return A<T>::t;`, но как это соотносится со стандартом и с тем, что VC++ 2015 компилирует спокойно? не знаю, не уверен...

Comment: Нашёл ещё одно решение. Писать `this->t`. Но почему так? Если без шаблонов, то и без `this` работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с поиском имен в шаблонных классах. Используйте квалифицированное имя или указатель this. Например,

```
template<typename T> class B : public A<T>
{
    public :
        T f() { return A<T>::t; }
};
```

Или

```
template<typename T> class B : public A<T>
{
    public :
        T f() { return this->t; }
};
```